# adding new row sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create data base that holds 3 pieces of information 
-name
-money
-comment
so I created this method in the databasehelper

```
     public boolean insertDataToHeader(String name,String money,String comment){

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(COL_H0,name);
     contentValues.put(COL_H1,money);
     contentValues.put(COL_H2,comment);

    long result = db.insert(HEADERS, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
 }
```

and the call method in the activity

```
    public void addHeaderToDatabase(){
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            moneyS=money.getText().toString();
             isInserted=MainActivity.moneyDB.insertDataToHeader(title.getText().toString(),moneyS,comment.getText().toString());
            backToMain(isInserted);

        }
    });

}
```

when I add two rows -name -money, for example, its works properly but when I add the third one it's not and the method returns false which means that the data have not been added.
that makes me think,is there a limited number of rows in the sqlit database?
** note**
the call is in AddActivity not in the mainActivity and the method `backToMain(isInserted);`
 return to the mainActivity if the data hve been inserted

Comment: if you are adding third column that is comment after you created the DB try Clear app data and reRun app ... no there are no limited number of rows

Comment: i tried  that many times + i removed the app completely and reinstall it and the same problem :/

Comment: Replace `insert()` with `insertOrThrow()` so that you get a useful error message.

Answer (score 0):

The comment string might be null and the column set NOT NULL, thus insert failing. A work around would be to check for a null before passing to the function insertDataToHeader.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        moneyS=money.getText().toString();
        String commentS;

             if ((comment.getText().toString()==null)){
                 commentS=" ";
             else {
                 commentS=comment.getText().toString();      
             }

             isInserted=MainActivity.moneyDB.insertDataToHeader(title.getText().toString(),moneyS, commentS);
            backToMain(isInserted);

        }
```